# Aiogram не отправляет сообщение в одну из групп в Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Вообщем, у меня есть бот в телеграмме, сделанный на aiogram,а так же 2 группы. В первую группу у которой ID состоит из 10 символов он отправляет сообщение спокойно. Во вторую группу, у которой ID более 10 символов он не может отправить сообщение, только если ответить пользователю в ней. Что не так?

Comment: Для начала проверить ID второго чата, верно ли оно? Кол-во чисел в ID не так важно на самом деле. Нужно смотреть код, возможно у вас ошибки, так что вернее всего было бы вам отправить тот кусок кода, который демонстрирует отправку сообщений в ту и другую группу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт.

Я решил проблему обходными путями (отправляю сообщение HTTP запросом через API). Так сообщение отправляется.